# Unknown SIGBUS error on Android production app

Tags: android, google-play, analytics, sigbus

I was looking for crashes on the `Playstore` console and found some crashes which weren’t captured by `Dynatrace`.
It seems like logs from `NDK` (which I'm not aware of) but the app isn’t built using it.

Has anyone faced similar crashing logs? Any help will be appreciated.

Full log.

````
  #00  pc 0x00000000000067ec  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!liba13e15.so
  #00  pc 0x0000000000006408  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!liba13e15.so (Java_com_c_b_b_a_NetworkFailureException_b)
  #00  pc 0x00000000001710b0  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline)
  #00  pc 0x00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub)
  #00  pc 0x00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*))
  #00  pc 0x0000000000319158  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*))
  #00  pc 0x000000000030f484  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*))
  #00  pc 0x0000000000680eb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static)
  #00  pc 0x00000000024ea2a0  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.c.b.b.a.NetworkFailureException.Protection)
  #00  pc 0x0000000000306a80  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13423079315433257381))
  #00  pc 0x000000000030ea70  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*))
  #00  pc 0x000000000030f468  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*))
  #00  pc 0x0000000000680eb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static)
  #00  pc 0x00000000024ea450  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.c.b.b.a.NetworkFailureException.getToken)
  #00  pc 0x0000000000306a80  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13423079315433257381))
  #00  pc 0x000000000030ea70  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*))
  #00  pc 0x000000000030f468  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*))
  #00  pc 0x0000000000680eb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static)
  #00  pc 0x000000000251ca10  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.android.getToken.blockingGetToken)
  #00  pc 0x000000000068115c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static)
  #00  pc 0x000000000251c9c0  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.android.getToken.$r8$lambda$7A2fQwUJSN70N0p9hvju4xJOmZw)
  #00  pc 0x000000000068115c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static)
  #00  pc 0x000000000251c8e6  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.android.getToken$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.get)
  #00  pc 0x000000000067fc38  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface)
  #00  pc 0x0000000002525854  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.functional.setFadingEdgeLength.BuildConfig)
  #00  pc 0x000000000068115c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static)
  #00  pc 0x0000000002525680  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.functional.setFadingEdgeLength.$r8$lambda$WD7zFXw7Sau2p1qfWvJ4F-3odLM)
  #00  pc 0x000000000068115c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static)
  #00  pc 0x000000000252508e  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.functional.setFadingEdgeLength$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.get)
  #00  pc 0x000000000067fc38  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface)
  #00  pc 0x000000000251ce66  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.android.getToken.BuildConfig)
  #00  pc 0x000000000068087c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct)
  #00  pc 0x000000000251cdc8  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.android.getToken.$r8$lambda$9ArEJ3CXnRnNfsIfpDP0DE180WY)
  #00  pc 0x000000000068115c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic)
  #00  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static)
  #00  pc 0x000000000251c964  /data/app/~~Num8ZM-Qg-SpGZ7oX8qRoQ==/au.com.amp.myportfolio.android-68V1eDl0oS2dRbvjrLtQUg==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.distil.protection.android.getToken$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run)
  #00  pc 0x0000000000306a80  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13423079315433257381))
  #00  pc 0x000000000066cc68  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge)
  #00  pc 0x000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge)
  #00  pc 0x000000000029d778  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker)
  #00  pc 0x000000000029a970  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run)
  #00  pc 0x000000000015ab08  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run)
  #00  pc 0x0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub)
  #00  pc 0x00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*))
  #00  pc 0x0000000000556650  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*))
  #00  pc 0x00000000005a5a74  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*))
  #00  pc 0x00000000000afce8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*))
  #00  pc 0x00000000000502c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread)```
````

Comment: YOu don't have to use the NDK to get a crash in C.  The ART JVM is written in C, and various libraries the frameworks use are written in C for efficiency.    However you didn't post the full stack, you left stuff off at the top.  What you shows tells us that it tried to invoke a static Java function Java_com_c_b_b_a_NetworkFailureException_b, who's name has obviously been changed via proguard.  SIGBUS is an access to an invalid memory address, but not a segfault.  Which means the address isn't addressable at all-  frequently alignment errors.  Can't tell you more than that.

Comment: @GabeSechan This log was copy pasted from the play console. I'm pretty sure this is not reproducible from our end and will be unable to put full logs.